# Java Timestamp accepting dashes

Tags: java, regex, timestamp, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I formatted a regex for HHMMSS.FFFFF as such:
^([0-1]\d|2[0-3])([0-5]\d)([0-5]\d).(\d{5})

and used to to create a SimpleDateFormat as such

```
 String format = "HHMMSS.FFFFF";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
```

Then tried to create a time stamp with the following data

```
new Timestamp(sdf.parse("1-1212.00000).getTime());
```

Using

```
121212.00000
```

it was good as expected.
Then tried to do it with such

```
1-1212.00000
```

And it still does not throw an Exception.
When testing the regex on regex101, the dash is invalid.

Why does Timestamp accept that dash with that regex?

Comment: Format `"HHMMSS.FFFFF"`?? `HH` = Hour in day (0-23), `MM` = Month in year, `SS` = Millisecond, and `FFFFF` = Day of week in month. Really??

Comment: `DateFormat` is not `Pattern`.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` probably interprets the `-` as a leading (unary) minus; but exactly what goes, I don’t know.

Comment: Beware that uppercase `M` is for month (not minute), uppercase `S` is millisecond (not second) and uppercase `F` is day of week in month (not fraction of second).

Comment: I got the caps from a Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine (DICOM) reference for a TIME field (TM) but even if HHMMSS.FFF is not what I want to use for a date format. the HH is correct for hour in day, so why does it accept a dash in the first 2 digits?

Comment: I recommend you throw away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`, instead. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: “why does it accept a dash in the first 2 digits?” I can only say that it’s because `SimpleDateFormat` is poorly designed and notoriously troublesome. With default settings it tends to accept to parse all kinds of input that you would never expect it to accept, and just tacitly give you nonsense results. Throw that class away and forget everything about it. Its `setLenient` method may sometimes make the situation a bit better, but I stand by my first recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of updating but JavaSE 1.6 is what I have and I can't make the decision.

Comment: Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Comment: Thanks, @user2568374, for the information that you are using Java 1.6. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @OleV.V. Which answer? Is there something else I can use If i have JavaSE 1.6?

Comment: Please add the closing quote `"` in your `new Timestamp`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format `"HHMMSS.FFFFF"` is:
`HH` = Hour in day (0-23)
`MM` = Month in year
`SS` = Millisecond
`FFFFF` = Day of week in month *(DoWiM)*

I don't think that's what you meant to do. But let's go with it.

Remember, all other fields are their default, i.e.
Year = 1970
DayOfMonth = 1
DayOfWeek = Sunday
Minute = 0
Second = 0

Input `000100.00001` parses to `1970-01-04 00:00:00.0`, because 1/4/1970 is the first *(DoWiM=1)* Sunday *(default DayOfWeek)* in January *(Month=1)* at midnight *(Hour=0, Milli=0)*.
This is your baseline.

Input `121212.00000` parses to `1970-11-29 12:00:00.012`, because `Month=12` makes `1970-12-06` the first Sunday in December of 1970, and `FFFFF=0` is then one week before that.

Input `1-1212.00000` parses to `1969-10-26 01:00:00.212` since it parses as `H=1, M=-1, S=212, F=0`, i.e. `M=-1` is 2 months before January, and `1969-11-02` is first Sunday in November of 1969, and `1969-10-26` is one week before that.

Comment: I know I didn't ask this but is HHmmss.SSSSS what I should be using?

Comment: `SSS` is *milliseconds*. Always use exactly 3 letters, i.e. `SSS`, not `S`, `SS`, `SSSS`, `SSSSS`, or any other length. `HHmmss.SSS00` might do, if you know last two are always zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I didn't ask this but is HHmmss.SSSSS what I should be using?

You asked now, and thanks for asking.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss.SSSSS");
    String timeString = "121212.00000";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, dtf);
    System.out.println(time);
```

This prints

```
12:12:12
```

`LocalTime` from `java.time` has precision of nanoseconds (up to 9 decimals on the seconds) but its `toString` method doesn’t print the fraction if it is zero. `121212.34567`, for example, is parsed into `12:12:12.345670`. Let’s try your string with the dash too, `1-1212.00000`. It results in a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1-1212.00000' could not be parsed at index 0`. As you had expected, the formatter refuses to parse the hours when the second digit is a dash. This also means that you have good validation in the parsing, so you no longer need any regular expression (regex).

The `Timestamp` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are both long outdated, though the latter is the more troublesome of the two. Also `SimpleDateFormat` supports only millisecond precision, there is no way it could parse seconds with 5 decimals correctly. Find the modern replacements in the `java.time` package. Use `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing. I assume you wanted to save a time-of-day without a date into an SQL database. If so, use an SQL datatype of `time` and a `LocalTime` in Java. `PreparedStatement.setObject()` will accept the `LocalTime` for saving. If your database column has type `timestamp` and cannot be changed, use `LocalDateTime` instead.

And while Andreas in a comment has explained why your suggested format pattern string of `HHmmss.SSSSS` would not work with `SimpleDateFormat`, it *does* work with `DateTimeFormatter`. Here uppercase `S` means fraction of second, so `SSSSS` means five decimals (otherwise many of the format pattern letters have the same meaning to both formatters, only not all).

### Question: can I use `java.time` in Java 6?

Yes, most of the above will work with your JavaSE 1.6, only not `PreparedStatement.setObject()`. You will need to add ThreeTen Backport to your project. This is the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (“ThreeTen” becuase `java.time` was first described in JSR-310). See the link below.

For saving to your SQL database, you will need to convert to an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Time`. For a time stamp you also need a date. For example:

```
    LocalDate epochDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0);
    Timestamp timeToSave 
            = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp(LocalDateTime.of(epochDate, time));
```

I took the epoch date of January 1, 1970, since this is also what a proper parsing of your time string into a `Timestamp` would have given you. I figure your DICOM can probably give you a date that you want to use instead. `DateTimeUtils` also has a `toSqlTime` method for converting `LocalTime` to `java.sql.Time`. Link to the documentation below.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Documentation of `DateTimeUtils`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html), the ThreeTen Backport class for converting between modern and old date-time types
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: As I mentioned above, my workplace is using JavaSE 1.6 and I can't change this. Is what you said possible with this?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to say. As long as you can decide on a dependency on ThreeTen Backport (and I’m thinking, only temporarily until eventually you move on to Java 8 or 9).